# Expanding UITextView in UITableViewCell similar to App Store "Description" Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitextview

In the iOS App Store, there is a cell for the Description of the app. If the text is too long, the cell has a blue "more" button which expands the cell to fit the entire text. There is the same functionality for the "What's New" section detailing the information of the latest update. I have tried implementing this with some problems.

Note: I am using AutoLayout in my Storyboard.

I have a UITableViewController subclass and a UITableViewCell subclass.

```
import UIKit

class SystemDetailDescriptionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let defaultHeight: CGFloat = 44

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!

}
```

The descriptionTextView is set in AutoLayout to 0 on the top, bottom, left, and right.

Next, we have a UITableViewController subclass. My first thought was to use the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if self.didExpandDescriptionCell {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(StoryboardPrototypeCellIdentifiers.descriptionCell) as? SystemDetailDescriptionTableViewCell {
                return cell.descriptionTextView.contentSize.height
            }
        }
        return SystemDetailDescriptionTableViewCell.defaultHeight
    }
    return tableView.rowHeight
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        self.didExpandDescriptionCell = true
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    } else {
        if let link = self.links?[indexPath.row] {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(StoryboardSegueIdentifiers.toVideoView, sender: link)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the contentSize is not properly sizing to the full length of the text. Instead, it's about 3/4 of the text. I have heard that this method will not work with AutoLayout and instead some trickery needs to be done with the LayoutManager, but those methods returned the exact same results.

Can anybody give me some insight on why this isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the text viewYou should try saying something like:

```
let newSize = cell.descriptionTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: cell.descriptionTextView.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.max))
cell.descriptionTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height
return newSize.height
```

You need to get the appropriate height for the content, then update the constraint to that new height (if you've set a height constraint), then update the cell height. This code assumes that there is only descriptionTextView in that cell and that it requires zero padding.

Comment: I did not explicitly set a height constraint for the UITextView. Instead, I set the bottom constraint to equal to the bottom margin of the UITableViewCell. When using the above code, I am getting unexpectedly unwrapping nil when setting the HeightConstraint. I tried switching to an explicitly set height constraint, but I am still getting the same crash. Are there any prereqs to using cell.descriptionTextViewHeightConstraint?

Comment: create an IBOutlet for the height constraint and call it descriptionTextViewHeightConstraint

Comment: I have added a height constraint set to 44 initially and Added the IBOutlet
@IBOutlet weak var descrptionTextViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! but the text view is not updating. I have tried calling layoutSubviews() and layoutMarginsDidChange() but the textView is staying at 44 height

Comment: You should call cell.layoutIfNeeded() Have you tried print(newSize.height) to see if it is a more reasonable number than what you were getting before? You may need to call tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic) again that might cause infinite loop though.

Comment: I am getting the same problem as the previous methods I tried. The method `sizeThatFits` is not actually returning a size that really fits. In my case, it is returning 133 but my text view actually needs something on the order of 200 to properly display the full contents (note I am using the default Lorem Ipsum text). To clarify, the cell IS expanding and more text is showing; the problem is that not ALL the text is showing.

Comment: Yes. I understand the issue

Comment: Is the text scrollable to the bottom? Have you tried changing the background colors of the textview and tableviewcell to see how both are laid out? I just ran the above code on the default text and it gave me a size of (237.5, 300.5) and all of the text was visible.

Comment: I have disabled scrolling because I don't want the textview to scroll instead just for the cell to resize, but I am able to scroll to the bottom if I enable scrolling. Setting the background color does not reveal anything surprising. It still simply appears to not be resizing properly. Would it be possible for you to package up your XCode Project and share that with me so I can try to find the difference between what you've done and what I have done? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The project appears to be blank, mate.

Comment: I really appreciate your tenacity in helping me with this problem. Even with following your code and Storyboard line for line, `sizeThatFits` is still only returning 183.5 which is not properly fitting the text view. I am getting up to the word `odioque` which is the second to last word. The final word is still being cut off. I have tried adding on the insets and adding a simple constant, but I cannot get the cell to expand any further. I really have no idea what is happening.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a uitextview and not a unlabeled with lines=0 and word warping?

Comment: I selected a UITextView because I was under the impression that it was the best choice for scalable text. Would a label be easier to resize to the content?

Comment: UILabels have an intrinsic size. If, you don't set an explicit height auto layout will infer it to be the intrinsic size. UITextView because it is scrollable does not have an intrinsic size, hence why it is necessary to programmatically set the size to the size of the content. Some of the benefits of UITextViews are they are editable and selectable and scrollable whereas UILabels are not. If you are not using any of those features, it is generally easier to use a UILabel with lines = 0 and word wrapping.

Comment: If I were to change to a UILabel, what would be the best way to get the height of the label? The only way that I can see initially is `label.frame.height` and it is not working as expected.

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the height, if you set up the constraints correctly. Just pin top, bottom, left, right. But you can call sizeToFit() on a label as well and it will return the necessary size for the label's content.

Comment: I don't think I am quite following. Using the label, how would I inform the UITableViewCell what height it should expand to? I have the Cell start at a small height like 88 and need it to expand to the entire size of the UILabel.